# Does ElasticSearch scan-and-scroll fetch account for updates?

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine i'm doing scan-and-scroll to perform an index migration. If i update a document during such operation, will i eventually see new version of that document in the document stream, or would it be just skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be skipped as a scan operasion is like a snapshot in time before the document was updated. So the next scan you do will get the updates. Here is a quout from `Elasticsearch` docs:

> The results that are returned from a scroll request reflect the state of the index at the time that the initial search request was made, like a snapshot in time. Subsequent changes to documents (index, update or delete) will only affect later search requests.

Hope it helps.